# link sent in mail to reset password do not work

Tags: php

I do receive an email to reset my password, but whenever I click the link, it should go to my "change_password.php" but it goes directly to my "index.php" which makes the user not be able to change or reset their password.

My link contains both the `id` and `code` I set, and the code in the database updates whenever the email was sent, but it's the link that doesn't work.

This is what my link looks like:

> mywebsite.com/change_password.php?user_id=29&key=233602

But when I click that, it should direct me to this page, my change_password.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include 'lib/password.php';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if($_GET['user_id']!="" && $_GET['key']!=""):
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['user_id']));
    $code=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['key']));
    $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE id='$id' AND `code` = '$code'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($fetch);
    if($count!=1) :
      header("Location:index.php");
    endif;
else :
    header("Location:index.php");
endif;
?>
    <?php include 'home-header.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>  
 <?php include 'home-navbar.php'; ?>

       <div class="modal-dialog">
        <h2>Forgot Password Recovery</h2>

        <div class="modal-content col-md-8">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i> Change New Password</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off" id="password_form">
          <div class="modal-body with-padding">                             
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label>New Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="passwords" name="password"  class="form-control required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label>Confirm password</label>
              <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" title="Password is mismatch" equalto="#passwords" class="form-control required" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>         
          </div>
          <div id="error_result"></div>
          <!-- end Add popup  -->  
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="id">
            <button type="submit" id="btn-pwd" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>              
          </div>
        </form>          
        </div>        
        </div> 

<?php include 'home-footer.php';?>
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#btn-pwd',function(){
      var url = "new_password.php";       
      if($('#password_form').valid()){
        $('#error_result').html('<img src="ajax.gif" align="absmiddle"> Please wait...');  
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#password_form").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {                    
            if(data==1)
            {
              $('#error_result').html('Password reset successfully.');
              window.setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = 'index.php?sucess=1';
              }, 1000);
            } 
            else
            {
              $('#error_result').html('Password reset failed. Enter again.');              
            }
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

But it's not directing me to that page, it goes to my `index.php` the moment I click the link. Why is it?

My PHP Mail:

```
 <?php 
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
  if($_POST['email']!=""):
      $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
      $db_check=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE email='$email'");
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($db_check);
      if($count==1) :
         $row=mysqli_fetch_array($db_check);
         $code= rand(10000,1000000);
         $link = 'mywebsite.com/change_password.php?user_id='.$row['id'].'&key='.$code;         
         $fetch=$db->query("UPDATE `profile` SET `code` = '$code' WHERE `email`='$email' ");
         $to="$email"; 
         $strSubject="Password Recovery Link";
         $message = '<p>Password Recovery Link : '.$link.'</p>' ;              
         $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
         $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
         $headers .= "From: no-reply@mywebsite.com";            
         $mail_sent=mail($to, $strSubject, $message, $headers);  
          if($mail_sent) echo 1;
          else echo 0;  
      else :
        echo 0;
      endif;
  else :
      header("Location:index.php");
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: what's the result of this statement: `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id='29' AND code = '233602'`? if you get anything besides exactly one row returned, you can expect `header("Location:index.php");` to redirect you.

Comment: You have two branches of your if block ultimately redirecting to index.php. First step is to change that so you can trace how those if statements are being evaluated.  Hint: They're probably not being evaluated the way you think they are...

Comment: @Felix - In `change_password.php` where you have your if Logics; Remove this portion and try again: `else :
    header("Location:index.php");
endif;`

Comment: i will try to echo that statement and see what will the result/s be @JeffPuckettII

Comment: Oh, okay, will try to figure that out. thanks @EatPeanutButter

Comment: check your `trim` function. Are you sure you want to `trim` `$db` and not pass `$db` to `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead?

Comment: i did but it still go to my index.php @andre3wap

Comment: omg i think it's the trim! didn't notice that! @@ will try it @imvain2

Comment: @Felix so it boils down to `trim()` first *then* escape ;-)

Comment: what do u mean? @Fred-ii-

Comment: This `$id=trim($_GET['user_id']); $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$id);` @Felix which does the same thing as the accepted answer. I'm just showing you the logic behind what I wrote earlier ;-) *"trim first, then escape"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone else is looking at the `if` statements, I wonder if its your `trim` calls that are the problem.

change this

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['user_id']));
$code=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['key']));
```

to

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_GET['user_id']));
$code=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_GET['key']));
```

you were "trimming" `$db` and not your variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be relatively straight-forward to troubleshoot. Try this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include 'lib/password.php';
echo 'STILL GOOD!';
exit;
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if($_GET['user_id']!="" && $_GET['key']!=""):
    echo 'DATA!';
    exit;
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['user_id']));
    $code=mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['key']));
    $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE id='$id' AND `code` = '$code'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($fetch);
    if($count!=1) :
        echo 'NO ROWS!';
        exit;
        header("Location:index.php");
    endif;
else :
    echo 'NO DATA!';
    exit;
    header("Location:index.php");
endif;
```

Notice the additional `echo`s and `exit` statements. Click your link, see which message you get, remove and repeat until you narrow down where it's failing.

As @imvain2 pointed out, `mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db,$_GET['user_id']))` should be `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_GET['user_id']))` so that is where your SQL query is failing to pull any results and causing the redirect to index.php.